# How to replace xml special chars manually?

Tags: c#, xml

My application produces an xml file that is then xslt transformed into a nice html report. I have a problem with \n however. There are some xslt techniques to do it, but they are pretty awkward and time consuming.

So my solution was to do a string.replace \n to

< br />

and then to force the xmlWriter to write this with WriteRaw(text). The problem is that the text sometimes has some illegal chars like >.

I am unable to find any utility method in .net that just takes in a string and transforms it in a xml-friendly string. I looked with the reflector and the class that handles this logic is not public.

Any ideeas (beside writing my own code to do this)?

Comment: Please submit your current code to The Daily WTF ( http://thedailywtf.com/Contact.aspx ). You'd get front page easily.

Comment: Dude, too harsh. At the very least, even if his code is the worst pile of steaming whatever, he is trying to learn better. That deserves respect at the very least.

Comment: Who cares? TDWTF isn't about learning, it's about laughing our asses off at people trying to parse XML as a string and failing. His current solution has WTF written all over it. He's got his answer from Tomalak. Now let's have a good laugh over his old, broken code.

Comment: Then what is "So my solution was to do a string.replace \n to <br/>" if not string parsing? Just what do you think string parsing is?

Comment: @Welbog: It's not string parsing if it's XML!  XML isn't strings; it's tags.  Duh.

Comment: Embedding HTML in XML is a use case. My report contains other HTML reports. So I really don't see a problem with replacing \n with <br/>

Comment: There is no problem with replacing \n with <br/>. It's the manner in which you sought to do it that is a WTF, especially since you're already using XML-parsing tools like XSLT and XmlWriter. These things are more than capable of doing what you want, in a manner than isn't hilariously broken.

Comment: I don't understand your point of view. At all. I am asking "how do I convert a string to an xml friendly string *USING .NET CLASSES*". I have already dismissed the ideea of writing my own code to do the *PARSING*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution to this question will help you:

[xslt replace `\n` with `<br/>` only in one node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561235/xslt-replace-n-with-br-only-in-one-node)

You can incorporate the provided template into your transformation process, and you're done without getting your hands dirty.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was aware of your post but I was searching for a faster solution. I now choose not to optimize early:).

Comment: Hm. That's a good decision, I guess. ;-) If you feel like it, you can post some performance measurements here. My guess is that it's actually not catastrophically slow. And it ensures valid output.

Answer (score 4):

**Never, ever use string manipulation to produce XML.**  It's not just that it makes poorly-socialized people laugh at you:  it leads to code that has bugs in it that you don't know exist.

Think about it from a test-driven perspective.  You've written a method that uses string manipulation to generate XML.  Okay, now write a test case for it that demonstrates that it will *never* emit poorly-formed XML.  In order for the test to prove this, you have to test every possible scenario outlined in the XML recommendation.  Do you know the XML recommendation well enough to be able to assert that your test does this?

No, you don't.  And you don't really want to, not unless you're writing a framework for XML generation.  That's why you use the classes in `System.Xml` to generate XML.  The people who wrote them did that work so that you don't have to.

Tomalak showed how to do what you're trying to do with XSLT.  If you're using an `XmlWriter` to generate the XML, use this pattern:

```
string s = "replace\nnewlines\nwith\nbreaks";
string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    xw.WriteString(lines[i]);
    if (i<lines.Length - 1)
    {
        xw.WriteElementString("br", "", "");
    }
}
```

This uses string manipulation where it's appropriate - when manipulating string data outside of XML - and doesn't where it's not - when producing XML text.