# Keep \n in Xml serialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class with some fields, as, for example,

```
public class Abc
{
  private String text;

  public String Text
  {
    get { return this.text; }
    set { this.text = value; }
  }
}
```

A stored procedure returns the object and I have to serialize it in a XML string, to display it with a XSL file. I serialize the object with this method

```
   public static String SerializeObject(Object pObject)
    {
        try
        {
            String XmlizedString = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(pObject.GetType());

            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode);

            xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject);
            memoryStream = (MemoryStream) xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
            XmlizedString = UTF16ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());

            return XmlizedString.Trim();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If the Text property of my object contains some new line characters \n, with the serialization they are removed and replaced with a space. How can I keep the new line characters after the serialization? Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5LpJ2c.  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  We would need to see 1) The source for the method `UTF16ByteArrayToString`, and 2) The initial contents of the string `Abc.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change approach, as I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561348/7057825) answer, I defined a template to call inside my XSL file:

```
  <xsl:template name="replaceNL">
    <xsl:param name="pText"  select="string(.)"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($pText, '&#xA;')">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
          <br />
          <xsl:call-template name="replaceNL">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

In my XSL I call the template in this way:

```
         <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <p style="padding-left:5px">
              <xsl:call-template name="replaceNL">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="Contract/ContractDetail/DESC_NOTE"></xsl:with-param>
                
              </xsl:call-template>
 
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

In my string that I passed to the XSL I can have a text in this way: `<DESC_NOTE>daFfF&#xA;ASFAFA&#xA;FGAGA</DESC_NOTE>`
But in the output I don't see the changes applied by the template, intead I see the text as "daFfF br / ASFAFA br / FGAGA", as if the tag  br/ is part of the text. What I'm missing?